Cannot show background events in resource timeline view
I have a fullcalendar component in Vue application with two event sources: regular events and background events. My problem is that background events are not shown in resource timeline view even if in month view they do!
I don't get any errors, simply background events are loaded correctly but not shown.
This is my configuration:
<FullCalendar :key="calendarKey" v-if="planningOptions" ref="planning" :options="planningOptions" >
  <template v-slot:eventContent="arg">
    <div :title="arg.event.title">{{ arg.event.title }}</div>
  </template>
</FullCalendar>`


this.planningOptions = {
  plugins: [ resourceTimelinePlugin, dayGridPlugin, listPlugin, interactionPlugin ],
  aspectRatio: 3,
  themeSystem: 'standard',
  headerToolbar: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek,dayGridMonth,listWeek'
  },
  slotLabelClassNames: 'text-center',
  resourceOrder: 'title',
  resources: this.initUsersResource,
  eventSources: [
    {
      events: this.initEvents,
      className: 'event',
    },
    {
      events: this.initNationalHolidays,
      className: 'national-holiday',
    },
  ],
  initialView: 'resourceTimelineWeek',
  resourceAreaWidth: '15%',
  slotMinWidth: '50',
  slotDuration: '01:00:00',
  slotMaxTime: '24:00',
  slotMinTime: '7:00',
  businessHours: {
    daysOfWeek: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ],
    startTime: '7:00',
    endTime: '24:00',
  },
  navLinks: true,
  nowIndicator: true,
  firstDay: 1,
  locale: 'it',
  timeZone: 'Europe/Rome',
  weekends: true,
  contentHeight: 'calc(100vh - 280px)',
  eventClick: this.showEvent,
  dateClick: this.createEvent,
}

This is my background event object:
{
  "allDay": true,
  "start": "2024-01-01 00:00:00",
  "end": "2024-01-01 23:59:59",
  "title": "Capodanno",
  "display": "background",
  "resourceId": null
},

I tried to set:
"resourceId": null
"resourceId": 0
"resourceId": ""
"resourceId": "X" --> a real resource ID

I'd like to show background events in resource timeline view too.
Am I missing something or is not possible? I haven't found any limitation warning in documentation.
UPDATE: I noticed that if I remove regular events source, background events are shown correctly.
Thanks

Not sure but maybe the configuration or even object does not make sense for a timeline view? Maybe it needs something different? There's no example for the timeline view?

For reference for other helpers: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-view

From what I've read on documentation there's nothing specific about event object for resource timeline view

This has nothing to do with it being a background event - the problem is you didn't specify a resource ID (or IDs) - therefore fullCalendar doesn't know, in a resource-aware view, where to put the event. If you specify a valid resource ID then it works fine - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/vYMwRvr . (I know you said you'd tried specifying that, but something must have gone wrong with that somehow - I've shown in the live demo that it definitely does work. You didn't  provide us an example of your usage of that in context.)

@ADyson Your example works because you only have background events as source. I updated the question: I use two sources (regular and background events) and I noticed that if I remove regular events source, background events are shown correctly.

Can you prove it? Because I just updated my demo to use 2 event sources and it works just fine: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/dyLExVg . At a guess, maybe it has something to do with those CSS classes you've defined on each event source? Do they make a mess of the display somehow, perhaps? Try removing them and see if it makes any difference.

Yes, you're right... I thought the problem was async sources loading VS hard-coded loading... but now it works both ways.

Ok. Glad you got it working. What exactly was the fix then? Was it related to the CSS in the end?

Honestly I didn't quite understand... for sure it's not related to the event object format or the configuration. I think it was something in the watch property where I resolve API calls through vuex and the sources' successCallback function.

Ah ok. Yeah obviously that isn't a factor in the demo I made - I don't know anything about vue so can't help you there!
